# How to show UIDatePicker calendar on tap gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uidatepicker, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UIDatePicker view that is embedded in a UIImageView. I want to create a functionality where when the UIImageView is tapped, the UIDatePicker's calendar appears on the screen. I also want the UIDatePicker to have a custom background color that matches the UIImageView.

[image]

What I tried:

1. Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView to make the  UIDatePicker a first responder
2. Setting UIDatePicker's backgroundColor to a custom RGB color (tried clear as well)

Is there a way to make the UIDatePicker's calendar appear when the UIImageView is clicked and add a custom color to the UIDatePicker?

```
class VieController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(section)
        section.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            section.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            section.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            section.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,
                                                   multiplier: 0.8)
        ])
    }
    
    lazy var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
        let picker = UIDatePicker()
        picker.datePickerMode = .date
        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        picker.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 246.0, green: 240.0, blue: 220.0, alpha: 1.0)
        return picker
    }()
    
    lazy var section: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView(image: Image.setButtonBg)
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapCalendar)))

        let calendarIV = UIImageView()
        calendarIV.image = UIImage(systemName: "calendar")
        calendarIV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        iv.addSubview(datePicker)
        iv.addSubview(calendarIV)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            datePicker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerXAnchor),
            datePicker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerYAnchor),
            calendarIV.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.centerYAnchor),
            calendarIV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iv.leadingAnchor,
                                                constant: 15)
        ])

        return iv
    }()
    
    @objc func didTapCalendar() {
        datePicker.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: you just want to open calendar ? from datepicker ?

Comment: Yes you can do it without compact DatePickerStyle by adding inputView on top of your image view. Keep inputView as clear color. It will look like date picker is open on  tapping image view.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed Yes, I want to open the calendar from datepicker when the imageview is clicked.

Comment: @AbdulHoqueNuri I will try that and get back to you!

Comment: @AbdulHoqueNuri I tried to add iv.inputView = datePicker in my code, and I get an error that says "Cannot assign to property: 'inputView' is a get-only property"

Comment: @NadiaSiddiqah, Add a textFIeld as inputView. It works.